# Is there any rule in commercial aviation, that two pilots in a plane cannot be a married couple?

Tags: airline-operations, pilots

Is there any rule followed or imposed by commercial airlines that the pilots of a particular plane may not be a married couple? My thinking comes from common workplace rules, where generally HR does not allow a couple to work in the same department, for obvious hierarchical issues.

Comment: Common comment: which jurisdiction? FAA? EASA? Else where?

Comment: @vasin1987 In this case I *doubt* it matters. I'm fairly certain that there are no legal regulations on this (though I would be happy to be proven wrong). If there are, it would be interesting to know about them, regardless of jurisdiction. But, I'm guessing that this question will have more to do with airline company rules, not legal.

Comment: @JonathanWalters: Your premise is in alignment with my thoughts.. Thanks for clarifying it..

Answer (score 6):

The Air Force, at least when I was flying there, had strict rules forbidding a husband and wife flying as crewmembers in the same aircraft.  Generally, airlines in the US don't have to have any similar policy, and there are plenty of examples of married couples (either pilot-pilot, pilot-flight attendant, or flight attendant-flight attendant) working a flight together.

An individual airline might be able to create such a policy themselves (although I have no idea if there would be legal grounds for a married couple to challenge the rule), but at least in the US there's no legal requirement that prohibits it.

Comment: Does this rule apply to ANG too?. There seems to be a [huband-wife team](http://archives.starbulletin.com/2004/08/20/news/story6.html) (or atleast was).

Comment: @aeroalias Dunno about the ANG, although that article never actually said that this couple flew together, just that they were the only married couple in that squadron. One could read it and assume that they do fly together, but if you start out doubting that they can, nothing in the article actually contradicts that idea either.

Comment: @RalphJ: I was referring to pilot-pilot situations in commercial aviation..Thanks for your inputs..

Comment: The Air Force rule makes sense, as it prevents a single accident from leaving orphans, with the added benefit preventing, well, reducing tomfoolery on long flights.